# SqlDataAdapter not update database

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqldataadapter

I am very new to VB 2015. I want to learn about database update command. I try to understand `SqlDataAdapter`. Could anyone please advise me? As my code below, it run completely with no error, but my database table (WORKSHEET) was not updated.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim command2 As String
    command2 = "Update WORKSHEET set cancel_flag = 'Y' WHERE CNumber LIKE @reversalNumber"
    Using con2 As New SqlConnection(WindowsApplication1.My.Settings.SaleCommDatabaseConnectionString)
        Using cmd2 As New SqlCommand(command2)
            Using oda2 As New SqlDataAdapter
                cmd2.Connection = con2
                con2.Open()
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@reversalNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "15332")
                oda2.UpdateCommand = New SqlCommand(command2, con2)

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    MsgBox("ggggg")
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SqlDataAdapter class is useful for applying changes from a DataSet to the database. Try filling a DataSet with the modified data, and then apply changes using the adapter's update method (`oda2.Update(WORKSHEET)`).

EDIT: Make sure that you fill the DataSet with the data by using the SqlDataAdapter's `Fill` method.

`oda2.Fill(yourDataSet)`
Before this, you need to select the proper command with `oda2.SelectCommand = YourCommand`.

Comment: I got a problem on how to apply dataset to oda2. I try code below, the error occured. It seem tb2 is a null object.

Comment: I should have been more clear. You'll have to instantiate a DataSet yourself, then apply the updates to the DataSet, then use the DataSet to update the table in your DataBase. This might help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I updated my previous answer. Be sure that you are filling the DataSet.